# flutter web : The difference between the local version and the version when uploading to the server

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

My application, when I test the debug version, shows the products and all things coming from the server, while when I upload the version to the server, the products or anything coming from the server that needs the Internet does not appear. I will attach pictures to you while testing a version. Local and when I upload the copy on the site.[image: local copy]

[image: on server copy]

Comment: Can you post the code where you are having issue?

Comment: I do not think that the problem is from the code, because when I searched, I found people facing the same problem that I experienced, but I do not know what the solution is.

Comment: Ok, I haven't worked with flutter before. But I have had this same issue when going into production with Vue and Vanilla JS, if you inspect element and check what the url of the img source it could help you point where the image is being built to.

Comment: The image is fetched from the server, and in the debug version it is fetched and displayed normally, but when patching the application it is not displayed, the image path is correct, otherwise it was not displayed from the beginning in the version. debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that this is a CORS issue.

To fix the CORS error on the server so that images can be displayed on Flutter web, you will need to add the appropriate CORS headers to your server. This can typically be done by adding a CORS middleware to your server code.

For example, if you are using Express.js as your server framework, you can use the cors package to easily add CORS support. Here is an example of how to do this:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

app.use(cors());

// Add your other server code here

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

Once you have added the CORS middleware to your server, you should be able to load images from your server in your Flutter web app without encountering CORS errors.

Note that you will need to configure the CORS middleware to allow requests from the domains that your Flutter web app will be running on. You can use the cors package's origin option to do this, as shown in the following example:

```
app.use(cors({
  origin: ['http://localhost:8080', 'https://my-flutter-web-app.com']
}));
```

This will allow requests from the domains http://localhost:8080 and https://my-flutter-web-app.com to access your server. You can add as many domains as you need to the origin option, or use a wildcard (e.g. '*') to allow requests from all domains.